# Как перезагрузить div с помощью кнопки на JS?

Tags: javascript, php

есть div, в котором выводятся данные из БД

```
<div id="showname">
 
<?php
  $user_object = mysqli_query ($connection, "SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `id`");
  while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($user_object)) {
 ?>

<p><?php echo $user['name']; ?></p>
</div>
```

и есть кнопка

```
<button id="reload">Обновить</button>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки перезагружался только div, а не станица целиком?

Comment: Перезагрузить див нельзя, можно сделать ajax запрос на сервер, вернуть какие-то данные  и с помощью методов dom дерева обновить данные внутри этого дива

Comment: Ну как минимум не ожидать, что тут что-то выполнится магическим образом. Вы генерируете страницу на сервере – так можно только полностью перезагружать страницу и получать новую разметку. Если хотите какой-то кусок перегружать, то изучайте AJAX и  подтягивайте новые данные (или кусок разметки) с сервера, заменяя старый код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы желаете что бы после нажатия кнопки "Обновить"- обновлялось имя пользователя, то создайте Ajax запрос который будет срабатывать после нажатия кнопки.
Пример:
HTML , тут на кнопочку вешаем событие onclick="upd()

```
<input name="random_go" type="button" value="Обновить" onclick="upd()">
```

После ее нажатие активируется Ajax

```
function upd(){
    var postData = getData('#blox_index_site');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/index/upd/",
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var result = data['result'];
            $('#showname').html(result);
        }   
    });
}
```

Также для корректной работы всех Ajax запросов необходимо добавить в файлик JS вот это

```
function getData(obj_form){
    var hData = {};
    $('input, textarea, select', obj_form).each(function() {
        if(this.name && this.name!=''){
            hData[this.name] = this.value;
            console.log('hData[' + this.name + '] = ' + hData[this.name]);
        }   
    });
    return hData;
};
```

Как Вы уже заметили в функции upd эта функция используется
var postData = getData('#blox_index_site');

Ну а в самом PHP прописать :

```
function upd(){
    
         $user_object = mysqli_query ($connection, "SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `id`");
  while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($user_object))

        //передача на страницу
        $array = array();
            $array['success'] = 1;
            $array['result'] = $user['name'];
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
```

Вы дергаете кнопочкой Ajax, он функцию upd, PHP берет/обновляет значение  $user['name'] и передает его обратно в Ajax, который в свою очередь обновляет только один блок div, а не всю страницу - $('#showname').html(result);

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: обратите внимание я обновил ответ. 
3-я строка снизу не $array['result'] = $user, а 
$array['result'] = $user['name'];